# How to repeat powershell command again and again?

Tags: powershell

Is there anyway we can repeat powershell script once it end? i want to run this command and once it complete i want this command to run again. i don't want to use task scheduler.

```
gci . -Recurse -Directory | % { if(!(gci -Path $_.FullName)) {ri -Force -Recurse $_.FullName} }
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-looping-understanding-and-using-do-while/ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually use while loop

```
while ($true) {
    # do something
}
```